# Cant build ios app after installing Firebase

Tags: xcode, firebase, frameworks, cocoapods, xcode9

I've followed all the proper steps to installing cocoapods and Firebase to my app, but for some reason, I keep getting the same Shell Script Invocation Error:
 /Users/Guest/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NewApp-eszjuaizunqxaofbuqgmicbnvqkh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NewApp.app/Frameworks/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework: No such file or directory

For this reason I cannot build and run my app. I've searched and followed all suggestions I could find, but nothing has worked. So far I have updated my pods, deleted Derived Data, and deleted everything from the pods to my project and restarted using my backup file.
 Can someone pleeease help?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common that happens a lot when using Firebase with Xcode! I assume that you are using CocoaPods to download the *correct* frameworks. A could of things to try: 
1. In Xcode go to the top bar and go to: `Product` -> `Clean` 
2. Just restart Xcode! (Make sure that all Xcode related tasks aren't running) `Command` + `Q` then make sure that its no longer in your dock running 
3. Go into terminal and run these commands to redownload your pod files

```
pod deintegrate
pod clean
pod install
```

If these don't work just continue trying these steps and it will <strike>probably</strike> hopefully work

Comment: Just do these 3 things until it works. This has happened plenty of times to me!

Comment: Thanks, but I tried each of these and still no positive outcome.

Comment: Open the Xcode workspace instead of the Xcode project.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the file and starting from scratch solved my issue